# what is the DEXT class for ACM data driver for creating nub?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, iokit, driverkit

am new to kext/dext and trying to port kext drivers to dext for development purpose.
In kext, for ACM data driver we created nub using IOModemSerialStreamSync class. 
In case of dext which class we will use for the same purpose?